# Use of environment variable in POM.xml doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to pull out the version number of the POM and all the dependencies to a environment variable. For example:

```
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>example-assembly</artifactId>
  <name>example-assembly</name>
  <properties>
    <current.version>${env.CURRENTVERSION}</current.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exceptions</artifactId>
      <version>${current.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>${current.version}</version>
</project>
```

With the above setup, when I run mvn clean command I am getting following error:

```
dependencies.dependency.version for example-assembly:war must be a valid version but is '${env.CURRENTVERSION}'
```

Any idea about what could be the issue?

Note: I am running maven in windows OS

Comment: And the exact command you're running?

Comment: mvn clean/mvn install

Comment: I don't think you can use properties when defining `<version>`. They aren't interpolated in this tag.

Comment: Sean,is there any other way thru which we can centralize build version of POM file/dependents.Basically in every 3 weeks we have a release and I dont want to source control the POM file each time by modifying the version number.For that sake I thought of externalizing the version number by putting in a environment varibale. I see usage of Env variable here in this link : http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Settings

Answer (score 1):

There is a better alternative for **updating Versions in pom.xml** than using environment variables inside pom.xml: [**Versions Maven Plugin**](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html). This allows you to change pom.xml using maven command line.

## Sample scenario

Project Structure:
  + P (Parent - Version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
  -- C1 (Child Project 1 - Version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
  -- C2 (Child Project 2 - Version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT also depends on C1)

### Task

You want to change version in all pom.xml files to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT

### Parent pom.xml

`<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>p</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Parent</name>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <modules>
            <module>c1</module>
            <module>c2</module>
        </modules>
    </project>`

### Child Project 1 pom.xml

`<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>c1</artifactId>
        <name>Child Project 1</name>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <parent>
            <groupId>sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>p</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
    </project>`

### Child Project 2 pom.xml

`<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>c2</artifactId>
        <name>Child Project 2</name>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <parent>
            <groupId>sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>p</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>sample</groupId>
                <artifactId>c1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>`

## Command

Command to set new version in all pom.xml files
`mvn -B -DnewVersion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT versions:set`
In case new version is represented by environment variable CURRENTVERSION
`mvn -B -DnewVersion=$CURRENTVERSION versions:set`
Here -B means --batch-mode (so new version won't be prompted on console)

## Resultant files would be

### Parent pom.xml

`<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>p</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Parent</name>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <modules>
            <module>c1</module>
            <module>c2</module>
        </modules>
    </project>`

### Child Project 1 pom.xml

`<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>c1</artifactId>
        <name>Child Project 1</name>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <parent>
            <groupId>sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>p</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
    </project>`

### Child Project 2 pom.xml

`<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>c2</artifactId>
        <name>Child Project 2</name>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <parent>
            <groupId>sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>p</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>sample</groupId>
                <artifactId>c1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>`

Answer (score 0):

The variable you define has the scope in the same pom.xml only and cannot be used in any other pom.
If you want to define the variable globally define it in settings.xml of maven.

Define the variable env.CURRENTVERSION somewhere in the the same pom, root pom or settings.xml
or else provide the exact version value in its place.

```
<properties>
    <current.version>'your correct version'</current.version>
</properties>
e.g.
<properties>
    <current.version>1.0.0</current.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Yusuf,Since I cant source control,I can not define the variable(which can be used by multiple POM files) in setting.xml file. At the same time I dont want to put the variable in any of the POM files.Hence I am planning to use an environment variable!